# Можно ли программно указать часть свойств hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Файл hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!-- Параметры коннекта -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <!--
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.63/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>
        -->
        <property name="connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
        <property name="connection.requireSSL">false</property>
        <property name="connection.useSSL">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>... + маппинги
```

Далее HibernateUtil:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

static {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure()
            .setProperty("connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.63/test")
            .setProperty("connection.username", "postgres")
            .setProperty("connection.password", "postgres");

    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Валиться всё с ошибкой, что не указан логин/пароль и url.
Возможно ли это вообще, указать только часть свойств конфигурации?
Hibernate 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно:)
В `setProperty` нужно писать `"hibernate.параметр"`
Пример:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure()
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.63/test")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "postgres")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "postgres");
```